# Theme handler with React

Tags: javascript, react.js, jsx

I've just created a theme handler with React.js.
Could my `Theme` component be polished and improved a bit ?

```
function Theme() {
  const [checkbox, setCheckbox] = React.useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("configuration"))?.dark_theme ?? true
  );

  React.useEffect(() => (
    !checkbox
      ? document.body.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
      : document.body.removeAttribute('data-theme'),
    setToLocalStorage({ dark_theme: checkbox }, "configuration") //memorization
  ), [checkbox])

  return (
    <div className="theme">
      ☀️
      <label htmlFor="theme-checkbox">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id="theme-checkbox"
          defaultChecked={checkbox}
          onChange={() => setCheckbox(!checkbox)}
        />
        <span className="slidebar"></span>
      </label>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Names! Calling a variable that represents whether the theme is dark mode or not `checkbox` is pretty confusing. Why am I setting a local storage value to `checkbox`? It took me a moment to unwind that.
- The comma operator inside the `useEffect` seems odd to me, but maybe that's how it's being done these days. I'd probably just braces around the function body and use regular JS statements.
- The line `setToLocalStorage({ dark_theme: checkbox }, "configuration")` will work fine for now, but as soon as you introduce more configurations it will (mysteriously) wipe out all the other ones every time this checkbox is changed.